# SQL Query that Create CSV file with Timestamp on it

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, scripting, sh

I created This shell script below, which fetches data from MySQL and create output as csv file. 
but I want to create this csv with a timestamp.
so I just want filename to be like this result_ddmmyy.csv

Is there any way to do this from script or from SQL query.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#scirpt to connect with db

master_db_user='root'
master_db_passwd='123'
master_db_port='3306'
master_db_host='localhost'
master_db_name='sagar_tb'


#Preparing script 


#MySql Command to connect to a database 

mysql -u$master_db_user -p$master_db_passwd -D$master_db_name -e  'select * into outfile "/created_files/result931.csv" fields terminated by "," lines terminated by "\n" from sagar_tb.test_table;'

echo "End of the Script"
```

Thanks and Regards,
Sagar Mandal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below commands in your script and update here if it works

```
    now=$(date +"%y%m%d")
```

And later add this in your file creation

```
    "/created_files/result_${now}.csv"
```